# Find the points of discontinuities of the function $x \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x^2+x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

Need to find the points of discontinuities of the function $f(x) = x \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{x^2+x}\right)$

Obviously at zero. I can’t take the one-sided limit ($\lim{x \to 0+}$ and $x \to 0-$) any way, sin is periodic, and at zero has a million oscillations.

In zero discontinuities, how to prove it. And how to get similar limits.

[image]

> sorry for lang. Frrrrom Rrrussia)

Comment: There are no discontinuities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are able to take the limit at $0$. Note that $-1\leq\sin(y)\leq 1$ for any $y$, so we have:

$$-\vert x\vert \leq x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x^{2} + x})\leq \vert x \vert\text{ for }x\neq 0$$

We have the $x\neq 0$ condition because we wish to inspect the function's behavior at $x=0$. Then, we have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}-\vert x\vert\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x^{2} + x})\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\vert x\vert$$

$$0\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x^{2} + x})\leq 0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x^{2} + x}) = 0$$

To prove that the limit exists, you can do the same thing with left- and right-sided limits. You will get that they are both $0$. This method of evaluating limits is called the squeeze theorem and it is useful when you want to find the limit of a messy trig function.

However, this function is still not continuous at $x=0$ because it cannot be evaluated there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that you can't take the limit as $x \to 0$.

Actually, using the usual bound $$-1 \le \sin (\ \text{something} \ ) \le 1$$
you get
$$-|x| \le f(x) \le |x|$$
Hence by the squeeze theorem
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $f$ is continuous at $0$, since, for each $f$ in the sdomain of $f$, $|f(x)|\leqslant|x|$, and therefore $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(x)$. Being continuous has nothing to do with oscillationg.

And, in fact, your function is continuous at every point of its domain (assuming that the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$ and that $f(0)=0$).

Comment: @joshuawang Did you actually bother to *read* my answer? I wrote that I was assuming that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined when $x^2+x\ne0$, so the domain is $\Bbb R-\{0,-1\}$. **It is continuous over its domain.** It would be wrong to say that the function is "discontinuous" at $0$ since $0$ does not belong to the domain of the function, so $f(0)$ is not defined.

We can however talk about the limit of the function at $0$.$$L=\lim_{h\to0}h\sin\left(\frac\pi{h^2+h}\right)$$ Note that $\sin$ is bounded within $[-1,1]$ irrespective of what is inside $\sin$. So as $h\to0$, the function approaches $0$, giving $L=0$. Alternatively note that $|f(x)|\le|x|$ and use the squeeze theorem to get $0\le\lim |f(x)|\le\lim|x|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(0)=0$, $f(x)$ will be continuous as the left and right limit abiut $x=0$ exist by sandwich theorem:$$ -x\le x\sin \frac{\pi}{x^2+x} \le x ~~~~(1)$$.

But by sandwich theorem (1) left lim is 1 and right limit is -1 about $x=-1$
the limit does not exist.So $f(x)$ is essentially discontinuous at $x=-1$.

Comment: you call squeeze theorem - sandwich theorem. In Russia we call this theorem - the two policemen theorem. Two cops and a criminal between them go to the same place

Comment: Lol. $-x$ and $x$ jailed $x\sin(\cdot\cdot\cdot)$ at $0$!

Comment: Yo Phosphene Very interesting I will tell others about it.